# No sound coming from Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio on my DELL Inspiron N7110 so that I can start recording some guitar videos. I use a Presonus Audiobox 96 to record my guitar tracks. I'm using Ardour for the default DAW that was provided with the OS but the one issue I am experiencing is that there isn't any sound coming out of the speakers.

Doing some research online, I found that JACK is required in order to get the sounds to come out of the laptop speakers but I have no idea how to properly set it up. I tried looking for some online tutorials but I have found no useful information. I've read from other posts saying to use Pipewire as a subsitute for JACK. I'm still very new to Linux. I have been a Windows user for many years and I figured I'd try out something new.

Comment: A quick Google search brings up this site. https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/easily-install-jack-audio-with-ubuntu-studio-installer/